# Uniqueness of maps imply a map is the needed one

Tags: category-theory

I am not able to formalize my question, so instead let me begin with an example:

**Lemma:** Given a functor $F: \mathcal C \times \mathcal D \to \mathcal E$, if $\mathcal E$ is complete, then for any morphism $c : C \to C'$ in $\mathcal C$ we have a map $\lim_{D\in \mathcal D} F(c,D) : \lim_{D\in \mathcal D} F(C,D) \to \lim_{D\in \mathcal D} F(C',D)$ that satifies that a certain square commute (not relevant but you can guess it).

Now, consider the following statement and it's proof:

**Proposition**: Let $F: \mathcal C \times \mathcal D \to \mathcal{Set}$ be a functor and let $c : C \to C'$ in $\mathcal C$. Take the limits to be the usual equalizer of products. Then $\lim_{D\in \mathcal D} F(c,D)$ is defined by
$$\lim_{D\in \mathcal D} F(c,D)((x_D)_{D\in \mathcal D}) = (F(c,1_D)x_D)_{D\in \mathcal D}$$

**Proof**: By the lemma, we know that a function $\lim_{D\in \mathcal D} F(c,D) : \lim_{D\in \mathcal D} F(C,D) \to \lim_{D\in \mathcal D} F(C',D)$ exists, but with the given data in the proposition, the only way to define such a function is the way we defined it; therefore, that must be the required function.

Note that we get "for free" that the required square commutes.

---

This proof seems to say the least, weird. However at the same time it seems right to me. Obviously, such reasoning can't apply for everything, because of nonconstructive proofs. However, it is not obvious to me that constructivity of a Lemma is enough to allow for such proofs.

My questions are then:

1. What are sufficient conditions for such reasoning be valid?
2. What, if any, is the precise formulation of the meta-lemma that's being invoked when doing such reasoning?

This comes from practical considerations, as this situation arises many times when working in category theory, specially in $\mathcal{Set}$. Some examples: RAPL, interchange of limits or colimits, the representation of functors as colimits of representable functors, etc.

---

My own attempt to 1. and 2. is:

**Conjecture**: Fix a formal system (e.g. ZF). Given a constructive lemma of the form "Given some data $D$ satisfying conditions $\psi(D)$, then there is a unique morphism $f:A_D \to B_D$ that satisfies $\varphi(f)$", if I have some constructively-obtained data $D'$ with $\psi(D')$, and furthermore given this data, there's only one function $f':A_{D'} \to B_{D'}$ that can be constructively defined, then $\varphi(f')$.

Comment: The reasoning is incomplete and does fail sometimes. Basically you have to check that the construction is not self-contradictory – usually, this is called checking for “well-definedness”.

Comment: @ZhenLin Do you know any counterexamples where the construction of the morphism in the general case is constructive?

Comment: Constructivity is not really the matter. The simplest (and in some sense universal) example is when you want to factorise a map $X \to Y$ as the quotient $X \to X / R$ by an equivalence relation $R$ on $X$ followed by a map $X / R \to Y$. There is only one way to do it, yet it does not always work – because you have to add the hypothesis that the map $X \to Y$ you start with is compatible with $R$!

Comment: @ZhenLin I'm sorry, but I'm not sure this is related to my question. The idea is to deduce that a particular definable morphism is the one that is given from a certain lemma, just because it's the only one we can come up with constructively. See my (finally written) conjecture for a possible flavor of my intention.

Comment: A relatively simple natural example where the usual categorical argument succeeds, but existence fails, is in trying to make a (genuine, categorical) tensor product of (infinite-dimensional) Hilbert spaces... which cannot exist, even in larger categories of topological vector spaces, basically because not all maps on (infinite-dimensional) Hilbert spaces are Hilbert-Schmidt (which would imply compact).

Comment: @FernandoChu It absolutely is. There is only one possibility for the map $X / R \to Y$, because $X \to X / R$ is an epimorphism. The proof that that there is only one possibility gives you the candidate for what it must be. Yet sometimes that candidate is not something that actually exists.

Comment: @ZhenLin I think this does not fit the form of my the requierd lemma in my conjecture. Written out, I think you mean "Given a morphism $f:X \to Y$ and an epimorphism $g : X \to Z$, **there is at most** a unique morphism $h: Z \to Y$ such that the diagram commutes". However, my conjecture involves lemmas that also (constructively) assure the *existence* of morphisms, not only the uniqueness. Am I understanding you right?

Comment: Your conjecture is problematic in other ways. "Constructively defined" is not a mathematical notion, for one thing, and in some contexts it is easy to "constructively" define a new morphism with the same domain and codomain as a given one. For example, in any additive category, given $f$, we also have $-f$. But $f$ and $-f$ don't always satisfy the same equations.

Comment: @ZhenLin I agree that constructiveness is not a mathematical notion, it is a metamathematical notion. Hence, as mentioned in my point 2., my conjecture is that one of a meta-lemma. The example of additive categories does not apply to my conjecture as we would have two functions $-f', f′:AD′→B$ (unless they are equal, but then I think the conjecture is plausible at least).

Comment: With what I do agree is that constructiveness is not well defined, as it can mean many things. For the record, I'm thinking of "constructive lemma" as defined as a lemma that can be proven in MLTT or cubical TT without any axioms; but, if the conjecture is true with this definition, I'd expect that it would work with some appropriate definition of "constructive" in ZF.

Comment: You are missing the point, I think, but I’m not sure which point. Additive categories are, in particular, categories. The usual formulation of limits applies. So your conjecture would also apply. Yet clearly if we substitute $-f$ for $f$ non-globally some equations would break. You should think about other ways to formulate your conjecture. (Consider that the formalisation of “all diagrams commute” with respect to monoidal categories is in terms of free monoidal categories.)

Comment: I do fear I may be missing the point too. The last assumption of my conjecture requires "there's only one function $f′:A_{D′}→B_{D′}$", so it doesn't seem to me that the conjecture would apply. Sorry if I'm being dense, if you would like to make your point clearer to me I'd be glad to continue in chat, if not, I understand.